# compare the list of object in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

how to compare the list of the object from an array using javascript 
here is an example

```
"listArry": [
 {
  "date": "2017-05-29T11:59:34.363Z",
  "status": "CLOSED",
  "name":"sam1"
},
{
  "date": "2017-05-22T11:59:34.363Z",
  "status": "CLOSED",
  "name":"sam2"
},
{
  "date": "2017-05-21T11:59:34.363Z",
  "status": "CLOSED",
  "name":"sam3"
},
{
  "date": "2017-05-30T11:59:34.363Z",
  "status": "OPEN",
  "name":"sam"
}
```

]

from this, i need to get only `new date()` object only

my output will be

```
{
  "date": "2017-05-30T11:59:34.363Z",
  "status": "OPEN",
  "name":"sam"
}
```

Comment: You need the newest date block? Or open status?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash library and in particular the find method to pick items based on your criteria: [lodash-find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

Answer (score 0):

You could just compare the given date and take the more recent object.

```js
var listArray = [{ date: "2017-05-29T11:59:34.363Z", status: "CLOSED", name: "sam1" }, { date: "2017-05-22T11:59:34.363Z", status: "CLOSED", name: "sam2" }, { date: "2017-05-21T11:59:34.363Z", status: "CLOSED", name: "sam3" }, { date: "2017-05-30T11:59:34.363Z", status: "OPEN", name: "sam" }],
    result = listArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

more powerful approach is order them and pick the first one

```
const orderList = listArry.sort( (a,b)=> a.date < b.date };
return orderList.pop();
```

Comment: not really, you need in the best case an average of O(nlog(n)) versus a single loop of O(n).

Comment: you look it not right, for that short list O() is don't matter. but now he end eventually with ordered list that he now know something about the member inside  . for example exclude the 3 top most update records

Comment: the big o does not describe the complexity on a given array, but rather describing an average of complexity on a random sized array. you are right, with small arrays and sorting. the complexity does not change.